# Check to see if a string matches a pattern

Tags: php, regex, string

If I need a string to match this pattern: "word1,word2,word3", how would I check the string to make sure it fits that, in PHP?

I want to make sure the string fits any of these patterns:

```
word
word1,word2
word1,word2,word3,
word1,word2,word3,word4,etc.
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
preg_match("[^,]+(,[^,]+){2}", $input)
```

This matches:

```
stack,over,flow
I'm,not,sure
```

But not:

```
,
asdf
two,words
four,or,more,words
empty,word,
```

Answer (score 6):

```
preg_match('/word[0-9]/', $string);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: I don't think that this is what he meant.

Comment: Sorry about that. The side-effect of using multiple langages. Ruby will take the literal. (or interpret the '' as delimeters.)

Answer (score 4):

if you strictly want to match one or more whole words and not comma-separated phrases try:

```
  preg_match("^(?:\w+,)*\w+$", $input)
```